# Kafka read topic --from-beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka

I've got a Kafka cluster with 3 brokers and 3 zoos. Topics create with 1 partition and 3 replication factors. When I'm trying read from topic with --partition - it's ok.

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my_topic --offset 0 --partition 0
```

But when I try read from beginning

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my_topic --from-beginning
```

there is no any output

```
Kafka version ./kafka-topics.sh --version 2.5.0 (Commit:66563e712b0b9f84)
```

Can you pls help me to understand maybe I missing some config properties, and how i can read --from-beginning?

Same thing at my Python code:

```
from kafka import TopicPartition, KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(auto_offset_reset='smallest', bootstrap_servers='my_server:9092')
**consumer.assign([TopicPartition('my_topic', 0)])**
msg = next(consumer)
for msg in consumer:
    print (msg)
```

it works only when i show partition 0

```
**consumer.assign([TopicPartition('my_topic', 0)])**
```

Comment: this is strange indeed. Just two things that came to my mind: in your Pyhton code your `bootstrap_servers` is set to `my_server` and in your command line call you use `localhost`. Probably just a copy-paste thing, but just wanted to make sure. Also, in your code you are using for `auto_offset_reset` is set to `smallest`. This value has changed in recent versions to `earliest` and seeing your version is meant to be `2.5.0` I am also confused....

Comment: Are 3 brokers on the same machine? Are they all healthy? What's the status of the consumer offsets topic?